# How can I use horizontal scrolling of a webview inside the viewpager?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-viewpager

On MainActivity, there is a ViewPager, which has several Fragments. The ViewPager consists of several fragments. One of fragments is a fragment that shows WebView. This WebView presents the content as a list of vertical items. Some of these items have horizontal scrolling. (Image : Horizontal item list 1, 2)

[image]

Due to the use of horizontal swipes in the ViewPager, horizontal scrolling within the webview cannot be used. How can I solve it? (If possible, with Kotlin)

Answer (score 3):

You can check this demo on Git with horizontal scrolling of webview inside the viewpager.

https://github.com/plusinfosys-global/Webview-Inner-Horizontalscroll-with-Viewpager

Answer (score 0):

its very possible, you must to define custom scroll on your view Pager, i have sample like this. just call method `canScrollHorizontally` from you webview on `TestViewPager` class

```
class TestViewPager(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ViewPager(context, attrs) {
    override fun canScroll(v: View?, checkV: Boolean, dx: Int, x: Int, y: Int): Boolean {
        return if (v is WebView) {
            v.canScrollHorizontally(-dx)
        } else {
            super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any luck with ViewPager2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to lock any other scrolling view while scrolling current view. Try this,

```
public static void LockScrollViewOnViewTouch(final ScrollView scrollView, View view) {
    view.setOnTouchListener(new android.view.View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        public boolean onTouch(View p_v, MotionEvent p_event) {
            scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
    scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new android.view.View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

This disable scroll on touch, first parameter "scrollview" is View you want to lock that could be your viewPager. Let me know if it works.